# Existance row in Dataframe based on other Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say, I have a Dataframe DF1 like this:

```
    A      B  
0  123    997  
1  123    998  
2  124    999  
3  125    997  
4  125    998
```

And other 2 Dataframes A and B, containing every possible item present in DF1:

```
A
     a      
0  123    
1  124      
2  125     
3  126      
4  127     

B
     b     
0  999    
1  998      
2  997     
3  996      
4  995
```

How do I check, in an efficient way, the existence in DF1 of every combination of rows in Dataframe A and Dataframe B in order to get a matrix of it?

Something like this

```
Existence matrix/dataframe:
       999    998    997    996    995
123  False   True   True  False  False
124   True  False  False  False  False
125  False   True   True  False  False
126  False  False  False  False  False
127  False  False  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.crosstab` + `reindex`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B).reindex(index=A.a, 
              columns=B.b).fillna(0).astype(bool)

print(df)
b      999    998    997    996    995
a
123  False   True   True  False  False
124   True  False  False  False  False
125  False   True   True  False  False
126  False  False  False  False  False
127  False  False  False  False  False
```

Comment: Nice one! ~ :-)

Comment: @Wen Thank you. Things have been slow today, it seems.

Comment: Sunday , Ummm, it is normal ~

Comment: @Wen Especially slow, since I haven't received any upvotes even after 4 questions (until you did it).

Comment: Totally got how great it is, it was just midnight Sunday